# Deleting sheets not found in lookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to delete unneeded sheets from a template once relevant information has been copied across. To do this I am looking up the sheet name with a check list. If  the lookup returns a value of `0.0` then I want to delete the sheet.

```
function myFunction() {

var studentsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Qj9T002nF6SbJRq-iINL2NisU7Ld0kSrQUkPEa6l31Q').;

var sheetsCount = studentsheet.getNumSheets();
var sheets = studentsheet.getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheetsCount; i++){
      var sheet = sheets[i]; 
      var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  Logger.log(sheetName);
var index = match(sheetName);

 Logger.log(index);
  if (index = "0.0"){
var ss = studentsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).activate();
    ss.deleteactivesheet();
}
  else {}
}

function match(subject) {

 var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14o3ZG9gQt9RL0iti5xJllifzNiLuNxWDwTRyo-x9STI').getSheetByName("Sheet6").activate();

  var lookupvalue = subject;
  var lookuprange = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 2, 14, 1).getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] });

 var index = lookuprange.indexOf(subject)+1;
  return index;
}
};
```

The problem is at the end when trying to delete the sheet. I have amended the code so it selects the sheet and makes it active but in the next line I am not allowed to call `.deleteactivesheet()`. Does anyone know how I can write this end part where I can select the sheet based on the index score being 0 and then delete it?

Comment: What is the exact error text? What is the line that gives the error? This is information that should be in your question body. Also note that you are using two or three spreadsheets here - there is no guarantee that a sheet in one of them is present in another.

Comment: I made the edit to the question as to where the error is. I am using two sheets one master sheet the other a template sheets that is edited due to the mastersheet. The last step is deleting extra unused sheets from the template.

Comment: That exact error message says that `ss` is `null`. It does not say that `sheetName` is `null`. If this is not a bound script project, there is a `null` return value for a call to [`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive)

Comment: ok. My problem is then how to delete the required sheet. I have identified them with the 'index' value but don't know how to select and delete the sheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving error message TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null on previously working systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729709/receiving-error-message-typeerror-cannot-call-method-getsheetbyname-of-null-o)

Comment: I made some edits based on this link but the original issue of not deleting the sheet remains. This has always been my problem with the code

Comment: Consider what it means to "activate" a sheet when there is no UI associated with the server that is accessing the spreadsheet. Also again, you need to write the *full* and *exact* error text.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know much about coding just trying to splice together snippets into something that works. I think I get where you are coming at but I am not sure how to resolve my issue. The error is from the last line `ss.deleteactivesheet();` It does not let me add the deleteactivesheet, only deleterows, columns etc. I don't understand why and how to delete the necessary sheet.

Comment: the exact error is `TypeError: Cannot find function deleteactivesheet in object Sheet. (line 17, file "delete")`

Comment: That error is correct - there is no method with that name. There is a method for a `Spreadsheet` object, that is similarly named - `deleteActiveSheet`, and not `deleteactivesheet`, but there is no method for a `Sheet` object to delete itself. Also note you have an incorrect operator in your `if` statement that checks what `index` is.

Comment: So to delete a `Sheet` where would i call the action from? The `spreadsheet`? With regards to the `if` statement can I just have `index = 0` rather than the `"0.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a `Sheet` from a `Spreadsheet`, there are two applicable `Spreadsheet` class methods (as always, spelling and capitalization matter in JavaScript):

- [`Spreadsheet#deleteSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet)), which requires a `Sheet` object as its argument
- [`Spreadsheet#deleteActiveSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteactivesheet), which takes no arguments

The former is suitable for any type of script, and any type of trigger, while the latter only makes sense from a bound script working from a UI-based invocation (either an edit/change trigger, menu click, or other manual execution), because "activating" a sheet is a nonsense operation for a `Spreadsheet` resource that is not open in a UI with an attached Apps Script instance.

The minimum necessary modification is thus:

```
var index = match(sheet);
if (index === 0) { // if Array#indexOf returned -1 (not found), `match` returned -1 + 1 --> 0
  studentsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
}
```

A more pertinent modification would be something like:

```
function deleteNotFoundSheets() {
  const studentWb = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
  const lookupSource = getLookupRange_(); // assumes the range to search doesn't depend on the sheets that may be deleted.

  studentWb.getSheets().filter(function (s) {
    return canDelete_(lookupSource, s.getName());
  }).forEach(function (sheetToDelete) {
    studentWb.deleteSheet(sheetToDelete);
  });
}

function getLookupRange_() {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some other id");
  const sheet = source.getSheetByName("some existing sheet name");
  const r = sheet.getRange(...);
  return r.getValues().map(...);
}
function canDelete_(lookupRange, subject) {
  /** your code that returns true if the subject (the sheet name) should be deleted */
}
```

This modification uses available `Array` class methods to simplify the logic of your code (by removing iterators whose only purpose is to iterate, and instead expose the contained values to the anonymous callback functions). Basically, this code is very easily understood as "of all the sheets, we want these ones (the `filter`), and we want to do the same thing to them (the `forEach`)"

Additional Reading:

- [JavaScript comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and this (among others) [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156112/if-case-is-always-true-but-probably-false)
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the time you spent not just helping me solve my problem but also trying to educate me along the way. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

If just like me you have been struggling to find a working example of @tehhowch above solution, here it is:

```
function deleteSheetsWithCriteria() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheetList = ss.getSheetByName('List'),
      list = sheetList.getRange('A1:A'+sheetList.getLastRow()),
      lookupRange = list.getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] }) + ',List'; // List of sheets NOT to delete + lookuprange sheet
    Logger.log(lookupRange)

  //Delete all sheets except lookupRange
    ss.getSheets().filter(function (sheet) {
      return deleteCriteria_(lookupRange, sheet.getName()); 
      }).forEach(function (sheetToDelete) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sheetToDelete);
      });
}

function deleteCriteria_(lookupRange, sheet) {
  var index = lookupRange.indexOf(sheet);
    Logger.log(index)
  if (index > 0) {0} else {return index}; // change line 19 to 'return index;' only, if you want to delete the sheets in the lookupRange, rember to remove the lookupRange in variable LookupRage
}
```